# окно в visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

прошу помочь, еще новичок в этом деле, работал в sublime text 3, потом решил перейти на vscode, что-то в настройках поменял с увеличением экрана и теперь вот: (картинка в описании*) Просьба помочь!)
[image: изображение]

Comment: `Ctrl +  -` (минус)

Comment: @Andrew какое отношение этот вопрос имеет к метке javascript ?

Comment: это не фотошоп*) Спасибо пробовал, не получается

Comment: Ну тогда откройте `settings.json`, уберите оттуда все, и возвращайте настройки по одной, пока не сломается.